# How to find where an input occurs within a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a simple hangman game right now, and I want to be able to identify where in a list a user guesses a specific letter. For example, if the word list was [D,R,A,G,O,N] -- and the user guesses A, I want to be able to get a return that would say 4...this is my failed code so far

```
import random

word_list = ['red', 'better', 'white', 'orange', 'time']
hidden_list = []
selected_word = random.choice(word_list)
letters = len(selected_word)
selected_word_list = list(selected_word)
game_playing = True

print('My word has ' + str(letters) + ' letter(s).')

print(selected_word_list)

for i in selected_word_list:
    hidden_list.append('_')

while game_playing:
    print(hidden_list)
    guess = input('What letter do you want to guess?')
    if guess in selected_word_list:
        print('Nice guess!')
    else:
        print('Nope!')
```

Comment: you want index ? for A it should be 2 or 3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `index` function of  a list

e.g.

```
>>> word_list.index('white')
2
```

But if the guess is not in the list, you will get a `ValueError`. You need to handle this exception.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to help. Please upvote and accept the answer! 

Answer (score 0):

```
# vowels list
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'i', 'u']



# index of i item is printed
for i in vowels:
    print('The index of:', i+" "+str(vowels.index(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A faster alternative to `list.index` is you could construct a `dictionary` of letter: index pairs using `enumerate`:

```py
yourlist = list('DRAGON')
yourdict = {letter: idx for idx, letter in enumerate(yourlist)}

guess = input('What letter do you want to guess?')
result = yourdict.get(guess.strip()) # Avoids KeyError on missing letters

if result is not None:
    print("You got it!", result)
else:
    print("Nope!")
```

For short lists, `list.index` is completely fine and you won't notice the performance gain of the `dict`, but for really long lists, it makes a difference:

#### Short List

list

```sh
python -m timeit -s 'x = list(range(50))' 'x.index(49)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.584 usec per loop
```

dict

```sh
python -m timeit -s 'x = dict(enumerate(list(range(50))))' 'x.get(49)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0733 usec per loop

# at this level, you really won't notice the difference on a GHz processor
```

#### Long list

list

```sh
python -m timeit -s 'x = list(range(500000))' 'x.index(490000)'
100 loops, best of 3: 4.91 msec per loop
```

dict

```sh
python -m timeit -s 'x = dict(enumerate(list(range(500000))))' 'x.get(490000)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0884 usec per loop
```

Note that for large numbers of items, `dict` scales really well